# What is the purpose of API token in REST API Call Plugin Configuration?

Tags: thingsboard

What is the purpose of "API token" option in REST API Call Plugin Configuration? Why it is compulsory?
On screenshots below it was set to "rest" but never used afterwards. Any examples?
https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/plugins/rest/

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the API token is to reserve certain path in the REST and Websocket API to particular plugin.

So, all requests that match certain URL filter:

```
http(s)://host:port/api/plugins/$API_TOKEN/
```

Will be dispatched to the plugin implementation after security check.
Plugin can apply additional checks if required.